# How to install an Android Wear app from the internal testing track?

Tags: android, wear-os, google-play-console

Through Play Console we have different tracks: internal testing, closed testing, open testing and production. Our testing process starts with internal testing.

Our deliveries consists of two builds: a mobile build and a wear build.

For mobile builds, we can send the shareable link so that our testers can click it on the phone and install.

**How can we achieve something similar for the wear builds?**

Note: Before there was a `Apps on your phone` section on the Play Store of the Wear device, and we would use that. But that section is no longer available.

Comment: Assuming that your testers have signed up for the internal track, you will typically see an available update within a few minutes if you visit the application listing in Play Store on the watch itself.